# Problem with React-Bootstrap/InputGroup caused by <InputGroup.Prepend>

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have been encountering a problem that I didn't have before.

**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**

I have a Searchbar.jsx component in my React that I export and then I import it in my Navigation.jsx component. The Searchbar component looks like this:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { Collapse, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import './Searchbar.scss';

export default function Searchbar() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    history.push(`/dashboard/?s=${searchQuery}`);
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Form className="d-inline-block" bsPrefix="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <InputGroup>
        <InputGroup.Prepend>
          <Button
            variant=""
            id="button-addon1"
            onClick={searchQuery.length < 1 ? () => setOpen(!open) : onSubmit}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} className="searchIcon" />
          </Button>
        </InputGroup.Prepend>
        <Collapse in={open} className="collapse d-sm-block">
          <Form.Control
            value={searchQuery}
            onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
            type="text"
            id="header-search"
            placeholder="Search..."
            name="s"
            className="border border-secondary"
          />
        </Collapse>
      </InputGroup>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

This is how I import it later in my Navigation.jsx:

```
    import Searchbar from './Searchbar/Searchbar';
    /*...
    ...
    a bunch of code
    ...
    ... */
    
      return (
        <>
          <Navbar bg="white" className="mb-3 px-3" bsPrefix="navbar">
            <Container className="justify-content-start d-flex-inline col-9 col-sm-6">
              <Navbar.Brand href="/dashboard">
                <img style={{ width: '100px' }} src={logo} alt="Logo" />
              </Navbar.Brand>
            </Container>
            <Searchbar />
        <>
```

I have made sure that export and import stuff the correct way.
As you can see I use React-Bootstrap/InputGroup and the problem seems to be caused by <InputGroup.Prepend> tag because as soon as I remove it, the error disappears.
What is more weird is that I don't get this error when I run it on my laptop despite it being the same exact code. So naturally I thought that is might be caused by different versions of react-bootstrap or, react-router-dom or even google chrome but I checked all of those and they are the same across my stationary computer and laptop. I get the same error across different web browsers on my stationary as well. I am really lost and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

// I just updated node version on my laptop and then yarn install in my web-app folder and now I'm getting the same error on my laptop as well. Could this be an issue with node or react-bootstap or react-router-dom? In that case what can I do?

//edit I have include my package.json

```
{
  "name": "profet-web-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "https://localhost:5001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.17",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.4.4",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.26.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "swiper": "^8.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.19.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.19.0",
    "eslint": "^8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "sass": "^1.39.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What versions of node.js are you using that worked and didn't work? Can you share your package.json file so we can also see package depenencies?

Comment: @DrewReese
I'm using node 16.17 now and earlier I was using 16.14 on my laptop which was when I was not getting the error.

Comment: @DrewReese I have now included my package.json in my original post.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found why this happens.
I went through react bootstrap documentation and found this:

dropped InputGroupPrepend and InputGroupAppend. Buttons and InputGroupText can now be added as direct children.

Link:https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/migrating/#inputgroup

Comment: I can confirm that I removed InputGroupAppend and used Button as a direct child, and now it works :)